# The Zariski density for two given sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$：
$ A = \mathbb{Z}^n$, and $B=\{ (z_1,z_2, \dots , z_n) \in A \text{ such that } z_1>z_2>\cdots> z_n\}$.

My questions：
Are these two subsets Zariski dense in $\mathbb{C}^n$? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following I don't distinguish between polynomials an their associated functions ${\mathbb C}^n\to{\mathbb C}$ - that's ok since we're in characteristic $0$.

> *Claim:* Suppose $f\in{\mathbb C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ vanishes on $A$. Then $f=0$.

*Proof:* Write $f = \sum_i g_i x_n^i$ with $g_i\in{\mathbb C}[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$. Then, given any $a_1,...,a_{n-1}\in{\mathbb Z}$, $f(a_1,...,a_{n-1})\in{\mathbb C}[x_n]$ is a polynomial with infinitely many zeros, hence the zero polynomial. Therefore $g_i(a_1,...,a_{n-1})=0$ for all $a_1,...,a_{n-1}\in{\mathbb Z}$, and by induction, each $g_i$ is the zero polynomial.

> *Claim:* Suppose $f\in{\mathbb C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ vanishes on $B$. Then $f=0$.

*Proof:* Consider $\varphi: {\mathbb C}^n\to{\mathbb C}^n$ defined by $$\varphi(z_1,...,z_n) := (z_1,z_1-z_2^2-1,z_1-z_2^2-z_3^2-2,...,z_1-z_2^2-...-z_n^2-n+1).$$ Then $\varphi$ is surjective and maps $A$ into $B$. Hence, by what we have just seen, $f\circ\varphi$ is a polynomial function vanishing on $A$, hence $f\circ\varphi=0$, hence $f=0$ by surjectivity of $\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This really helped me.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, since you seem to be interested in Lie theory: the density of $B$ is important there since it can be viewed as the set of dominant integral weights for a given semisimple Lie algebra. Or was that your motivation anyway? :)

Comment: What an ingenious idea, Hanno : +1, since unfortunately I can only upvote once :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thank you, I'm happy you like it!

Comment: @Hanno: Yes, the motivation of the above problem comes from Lie theory. I often encounter it, but I am not aware how to prove it until your prove it. Thanks again :)!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are.

Some general facts that will take care of the answer:

A set $A$ of form
$A= A_1 \times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_n$ is Zariski dense if all of the $A_i$ are infinite. That takes care of the $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

A nonvoid set  open in the standard topology is Zariski dense. This is because it contains an open cube $S \times S \times \ldots \times S$ and you apply the previous result. That will take care of your second set.

$\bf{Added:}$

I misread the statement, $B$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Yes, it is still Zariski dense. Consider $\mathbb{N}_{>0}^n$. This is Zariski dense. Now we should notice that the image on a Zariski dense subset under a linear bijection is again Zariski dense. Hence the set 
$$\{ (a_1, a_1 + a_2, \ldots, a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n )\ | a_i \in \mathbb{N}_{>0} \}$$  is Zariski dense.

Reverse the order of the coordinates and get a Zariski dense subset contained in $B$.

Comment: Dear orangeskid, the second set $B\subset \mathbb Z^n$ is not open in the standard topology, so your argument does not apply.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Oh, thank you, I misread the statement, the argument has to be modified.

Comment: +1: Very nice now! Two nitpicks: 1) you should replace $\mathbb N$ by $\mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$ [you are not one of those #@&% people for whom $0\notin \mathbb N$, are you ?]  2) Your solution should be read from right to left since the order relation defining $B$ is $\gt$  [of course it is correct for readers of Arabic or Hebrew :-)]

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Hi, Georges, thank you!  I agree, $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$.  And I should also flip the order of the coordinates.